# Make stroke uniform from curves imported from a .pdf or .ps

Tags: inkscape

I use Inkscape for work, and I often have to import curves from .ps or .pdf file to then fit them into a schematic or a scale. The problem is that I often have no control on the ps/pdf file, and if I must significantly rescale the curve, it exhibit different stroke widths. I can easily create another path using :tool_node: that follows almost exactly the original path, but this is a inelegant and time-consuming process. Therefore, I am looking for a way to make a non-uniform stroke uniform, e.g with the same width accross the whole curve.

[image]

I have included the example above [here](https://mega.nz/#!kcMkyDhS!LYtBgMp1qKZIKLNz8JRPqTL4MdFoA88ayuK0gDed4yg), in hope it helps.

Comment: Your path is in a group with a [transformation matrix](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Transforms.html) applied (hence the *calligraphic* effect). Try to ungroup it or to remove the transformation. And the path is full of unconnected vertex too. Try to write your own answer, now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Ungrouping does work, but how do you see whether a transformation matrix is applied ?

Comment: The fastest way is reading the XML source.

Answer (score 1):

Deactivating *when scaling objects, scale the stroke width by the same proportion* should do the trick for you:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not the issue here. When importing a path from a PDF, it apparently comes in a group with a transformation matrix that affects the stroke width. As a result, the stroke becomes non-uniform when rescaled, whether this option is enabled or disabled. A solution here is to ungroup then to regroup everything again, as indicated by @Paolo Gibellini.

Comment: @HcN: Still, what I described circumvened the problem for your example file for me.